# Implementing Custom Product Clustering with One Product Per Store and mBERT Embeddings

Tags: python, nlp, cluster-analysis, k-means, bert-language-model

I'm working on a product clustering algorithm for an assortment of products from 7 different stores. The goal is to create clusters of similar products with the constraint that each cluster should contain at most one product per store. Keep in mind that my database contains around 90k different product descriptions.

Previously, I used a TF-IDF (with some preprocessing) approach with cosine similarity to assess product similarities, followed by a weighted average of the similarity score, weight, and price to get a final score for clustering.

However, this method allowed a product to belong to multiple clusters, leading to ambiguity in determining the final store for a product. For example, product A might be similar to B, C, and D, but B might be similar to C, D, and E, and so on. This overlap makes it unclear how to definitively assign products to clusters.

To improve this, I've switched to using mBERT embeddings instead of TF-IDF for product descriptions. The rest of the algorithm remains similar, but I'm still facing the challenge of creating distinct clusters with the one-product-per-store constraint.

I'm considering using a k-means clustering algorithm, but I'm unsure how to incorporate the constraint that each cluster can only contain one product from each store. Here's what I need help with:

1. Cluster Uniqueness: How can I ensure that a product is only assigned to one cluster given the overlapping similarities? Is there a method to prevent products from being part of multiple clusters?
2. Adapting k-means for Custom Constraints: How can I modify the k-means algorithm to ensure that each cluster has at most one product per store? Is there a way to integrate this constraint into the centroid update step or during the assignment of products to clusters?
3. Handling mBERT Embeddings: Are there specific considerations I should take into account when using mBERT embeddings with clustering algorithms like k-means?
4. Are there any other alternatives that I have missed?

Any insights or suggestions on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated, especially code examples or references to similar implementations.